# How to display multiple record as table head and final based on table head

Tags: php, html, mysql

I confused about the title that i want to ask. I'm working on this, when i want to see students report the value for each theme.

Below is my subject table on database.

```
+-----------+----------------------+----------------------+
| SubjectID |      SubjectName     |       ThemeName      |
+-----------+----------------------+----------------------+
|     1     |       Subject1       |        Myself        |
|     2     |       Subject1       |       My Hobbies     |
|     3     |       Subject1       |      My Activity     |
|     4     |       Subject1       |       My Family      |
|     5     |       Subject2       |     My Experience    |
|     6     |       Subject2       |      Environment     |
|     7     |       Subject2       |        Things        |
|     8     |       Subject2       |     Nature Incident  |
+-----------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

And this one is table value for each theme.

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|  ValueID  | StudentID | SubjectID | FinalScore |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|     1     |    112    |     1     |     80     |
|     2     |    112    |     2     |     90     |
|     3     |    112    |     3     |     50     |
|     4     |    112    |     4     |     70     |
|     5     |    113    |     1     |     60     |
|     6     |    113    |     2     |     40     |
|     7     |    113    |     3     |     50     |
|     8     |    113    |     4     |     90     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

I want to display on my html just like table below

```
+----+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| No | StudentID | ThemeName1 | ThemeName2 | ThemeName3 | ThemeName3 |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 1  |    112    |     80     |     90     |     50     |     70     |
| 2  |    113    |     60     |     40     |     50     |     90     |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

This table that i'm working now. Ignore for an empty , i will delete it soon.

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table display table-bordered" id="table1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="1%"><center>No</th>
                        <th width="10%"><center>Nama Siswa</th>
                        <th width="12%"><center>Nama Mapel</th>
                        <th width="25%"><center>Diri Sendiri</th>
                        <th width="5%"><center>Kegemaranku</th>
                        <th width="5%"><center>Kegiatanku</th>
                        <th width="5%"><center>Keluargaku</th>
                        <th width="5%"><center>TG4</th>
                        <th width="1%"><center>Aksi</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $no = 1;
                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT NISN, MAX(CASE WHEN KodeMapel = 29 THEN NilaiAkhir END) AS Diri Sendiri, MAX(CASE WHEN KodeMapel = 30 THEN NilaiAkhir END) AS Kegemaranku, MAX(CASE WHEN KodeMapel = 31 THEN NilaiAkhir END) AS Kegiatanku, MAX(CASE WHEN KodeMapel = 32 THEN NilaiAkhir END) AS Keluargaku FROM pengetahuan
                        GROUP BY NISN");
                        while ($pengetahuan = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
                        {
                            $kode       = $pengetahuan['KodeP'];
                            $nisn       = $pengetahuan['NISN'];
                            $namasiswa  = $pengetahuan['NamaSiswa'];
                            $namatema   = $pengetahuan['NamaTema'];
                            $namamapel  = $pengetahuan['NamaMapel'];
                            $na         = $pengetahuan['NilaiAkhir'];
                    ?>  
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <center>
                                    <?php echo $no++; ?>
                                </center>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <center><?php echo $namasiswa; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <center><?php echo $namamapel; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $na; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <center>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <center>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <center>
                                <?php 

                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <center>
                                <?php 

                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <center>
                                <?php 

                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <center>
                                <?php

                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <center>
                                <?php

                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <center>
                                    <button data-id="<?php echo "$kode"; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal12"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i> Tambah Nilai</button>
                                    <a href="Pengetahuan/Tema4/action.php?KodeP= <?php echo $$kode; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="submit" type="submit"/>
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></i> Hapus </a>
                                </center>   
                            </td>       
                        </tr>
                    <?php                               
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Is it possible to do?
Thank you

Comment: user `right join` in mysql query

Comment: If theme names could be more than this, then consider implementing `dynamic pivot`, Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns) for the same.

Comment: Handle issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following pivot query to get the general table you want in your output:

```
SELECT
    StudentID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN SubjectID = 1 THEN FinalScore END) AS ThemeName1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN SubjectID = 2 THEN FinalScore END) AS ThemeName2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN SubjectID = 3 THEN FinalScore END) AS ThemeName3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN SubjectID = 4 THEN FinalScore END) AS ThemeName4
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY StudentID
```

To generate the `No` column, you can handle this in your PHP code when you iterate over the result set.

Comment: It returns warning message : mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in. I'm using while to do the query.

Comment: I can't see your code so therefore I cannot help you.

Comment: See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) for documentation on `mysql_fetch_array()`.  From what I read, this function/API is deprecated and you should upgrade.

Comment: My view is that, in the context of application code, this answer is not useful.

Comment: If the answer is accepted, it means it works for OP and that is a sufficient evidence that the answer *is* useful.